My mother thinks that my sister is infected with evil eye so she was using an egg to get rid of the evil eye. Is it shirk?
My sister has been experiencing signs of evil eye so my mother used a raw egg to wave around my whole sisters body  while reciting some dua or the 4 kuls (I'm not sure what exactly she said). I found this extremely weird and sketchy but I couldn't stop her no matter how hard I tried. Later, she went outside and threw it on the ground and said some birds will come eat it. I'm very confused on what she did and if its shirk or not. Please tell me ! Thank you.

Neither duas nor quls are shirk, and the egg was not worshiped but simply used. I don't think folk remedies as such are shirk. Waiting for an answer based on Islam.

Most people including believers live in Shirk, but that's almost ok!

وَ مَا يُؤْمِنُ أَكْثَرُهُمْ بِاللَّهِ إِلَّا وَ هُمْ مُشْرِكُونَ
And most of them believe not in Allah except while they associate
others with Him.

it is not really ok in the strict sense, but it is ok in the sense that this Shirk is not that Shirk that is assumed the greatest sin:

إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَغْفِرُ أَنْ يُشْرَكَ بِهِ وَ يَغْفِرُ مَا دُونَ
ذَلِكَ لِمَنْ يَشَاءُ وَ مَنْ يُشْرِكْ بِاللَّهِ فَقَدْ ضَلَّ ضَلَالًا
بَعِيدًا
Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives
what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others
with Allah has certainly gone far astray.

Indeed Shirk is graded like believing is graded. The Shirk mostly blamed is called the manifested Shirk (شرک جلیّ), in which the person explicitly worship someone/something beside Allah/the God. But the former shirk, which almost all of us are smeared with is called the Hidden Shirk (شرک خفیّ). In Ahadeeth it is stated that the hidden shirk is sometimes more hidden than a black ant over a black stone in a dark night. Whenever you drink water because you feel thirsty and you assume drinking water will stop your thirst, that would be a hidden shirk, because it is indeed Allah who stops your thirst, as Allah has characterizing water to have such an effect.

ز یزدان دان، نه از ارکان، که کوته‌دیدگی باشد که خطی کز عنان خیزد تو آن
را از بنان بینی
identify every effect to be from Allah, as it is unwise to see a
beautiful hand writing an praise the fingers instead of the writer

This is called Tawhid Af'ali, which is abstracted in "لا حول و لا قوة الّا بالله". So your mother if uses an egg for a benefit, that is not more shirk than you drink water to stop your thirst. However, this specific story has also another aspect. That water really stops the thirst, but does an egg really prevents/stops/negates evil eye? Is there a verse or Hadeeth about it? Probably not, but we do not seek root in Hadeeth/Quran for many other statements we accept e.g. from scientists. Therefore, maybe not very different in that regard as well. But if your mother does what she does and claims it to be the command of God at the same time that she knows it is not, then that would be another sin, the innovation:

وَ مَنْ أَظْلَمُ مِمَّنِ افْتَرَيٰ عَلَي اللَّهِ كَذِبًا
Who doth more wrong than he who inventeth a lie about Allah

So relax, I personally doubt if this is a major Shirk, or an innovation, although better to avoid if there is no authenticate source for it. People usually recite these verses of Quran to prevent evil eye, as far as I have seen:

وَ إِنْ يَكَادُ الَّذِينَ كَفَرُوا لَيُزْلِقُونَكَ بِأَبْصَارِهِمْ
لَمَّا سَمِعُوا الذِّكْرَ وَ يَقُولُونَ إِنَّهُ لَمَجْنُونٌ . وَ مَا
هُوَ إِلَّا ذِكْرٌ لِلْعَالَمِينَ
And indeed, those who disbelieve would almost make you slip with their
eyes when they hear the message, and they say, 'Indeed, he is mad.
But it is not except a reminder to the worlds.

or give money to charity (صدقة), or things like that ...

Good answer, but then, can we ever get rid of "the Hidden Shirk"? Looks to me like the "woke" or "cancel culture": whatever someone does, someone else can call it evil.

@GyroGearloose, simply understand any and every effect is from Allah; then if you feel seek go to a hospital and do whatever you usually do, but know Allah affects you the way He will, and every doctor, nurse, medication, drug and else are tools Allah manages them; if you feel hungry eat food but know that only Allah compensates your hunger and foods are only tools, and tools will not affect the way they usually work if Allah wants the reverse,

(Ibrahim's knife didn't cut Isma'il's neck, fire doesn't burn Ibrahim, water may not remove thirst no matter how much one person with some specific illness drinks, some drugs which work correctly on most people will have the opposite effect on a single person, a ship which is the greatest creation of humanity will not survive a simple sea travel and will sink after a simple accident, and etc.). Imam Ali PBUH once said I identified Allah in decision making opportunities, I made decision to reach a certain goal but something else happened, if my memories help.

no need to cancel culture, culture is good in many ways, it give coherence to people, it make people eager to know each other, like Allah created people differently for them to know each other: "يَا أَيُّهَا النَّاسُ إِنَّا خَلَقْنَاكُمْ مِنْ ذَكَرٍ وَ أُنْثَيٰ وَ جَعَلْنَاكُمْ شُعُوبًا وَ قَبَائِلَ لِتَعَارَفُوا", and culture is one of the aspects of being of different " شُعُوبًا وَ قَبَائِلَ". Only some (and I guess minor in most cases) cultural rituals may be discouraged or forbidden, not all or even most or perhaps many.

Here in Iran we celebrate our own national ceremonies, we celebrate birthdays, we have our own way of dressing, we have our own dishes and foods, these are not bad or even discouraged, but in most cases encouraged.

I didn't understood the point you made about evil acts, why you think it to be so?

So what you are saying is that hidden Shrik is not about what someone is doing, but is a state of mind. I think I was not clear enough about "cancel culture", I was referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancel_culture
